# Append Histogram Class Objects to a list elements in R

Tags: r, list, class, histogram

My title's problem is very similar to a lot of's in SOF, though my problem is very different :
I got a list `MY_LIST`.

```
MY_LIST=list("a","b","c")
```

I got a histogram class object `HIST_OBJECT`.

```
HIST_OBJECT=hist(rnorm(n=500, m=1, sd=1))
class(HIST_OBJECT)
[1] "histogram"
```

I want to load my `HIST_OBJECT` into the 1st slot of my list `MY_LIST`. So i execute that :

```
MY_LIST[[1]][2]=list(HIST_OBJECT)
```

So far so good but the problem is that the class of my `HIST_OBJECT` has changed. It was an histogram class that i could plot (`plot(HIST_OBJECT)` works!) but now it's a list class that I can't plot anymore (`plot(MY_LIST[[1]][2]`) don't work)

```
class(MY_LIST[[1]][2])
[1] "list"
```

Does anyone know how to do in order to make `MY_LIST[[1]][2]` object an "histogram" class object? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
class(MY_LIST[[1]][[2]])
```

Think of a list like a train: a single `[` gets the carriage you want with all its contents, a double `[[` gets just the contents of that carriage. Also think why  `MY_LIST[[1]][2]=HIST_OBJECT` does not work, but `MY_LIST[[1]][[2]]=HIST_OBJECT` does.

In this case, the `[2]` got you the same class as its container - a list, containing the second element, your hist. The `[[2]]` will get you the element in the second container, in this case your hist.

Another example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,5,6))
class(df[1])
class(df[[1]])
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much for helping me! I look so dumb§ Thanks for the explanations, I really appreciate it!!